# When registering script reference, one disable another one

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Here is my code, i don't know the reason but when registering the last 3 java-scripts the first 2 disabled i also tried to register them in the head tag but same problem, thanks..

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMain" runat="server" >
 <CompositeScript>  
        <Scripts>  
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/AutoComplete/jquery.min.js" />  
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/AutoComplete/jquery-ui.min.js" /> 

            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/LoginScripts/mootools-1.2-core-yc.js" />  
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/LoginScripts/mootools-1.2-more.js" />  
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/LoginScripts/fx.slide.js" />  
        </Scripts>  
    </CompositeScript> 
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: are they disabled or combined in one script ? (They should be combined)

Comment: the autocomplete scripts disabled as they aren't wrote

Comment: well that don't describe problem good enough that anyone can help you. What exactly do you mean by "aren't wrote", script links are not rendered in html or script it self is not complete ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<CompositeScript>` element:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="myScriptManager" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/LoginScripts/mootools-1.2-core-yc.js" />  
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/LoginScripts/mootools-1.2-more.js" />  
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/LoginScripts/fx.slide.js" />  
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Then you will have three separate `<script/>` references.

If you are using `CompositeScript` feature, ASP.NET will combine scripts in one. This reduces the number of browser requests. But to make it work, use following structure (you can optionally set the path to generated single script in `Path` attribute of `CompositeScript` element):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="myScriptManager" runat="server">
   <Scripts>
     <CompositeScript Path="~/Scripts/single.js">
       <Scripts>
         <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/LoginScripts/mootools-1.2-core-yc.js" />  
         <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/LoginScripts/mootools-1.2-more.js" />  
         <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/LoginScripts/fx.slide.js" />  
       </Scripts>
     </CompositeScript>
   </Scripts>
 </asp:ScriptManager>
```